# problem in ordering categorical dtype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dtype

I'm trying to convert dtype to categorical and having trouble in the order
this is the code I used:

```
clarity_deg = ['I1', 'SI2', 'SI1', 'VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VVS1', 'IF']
clarity_lvl = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(ordered=True, categories=clarity_deg)

diamonds['clarity'] = diamonds['clarity'].astype(clarity_lvl)
plt.hist(data = diamonds, x = 'clarity')
```

it keep showing in different order in plt.hist()

[image: matplotlib histogram output]

thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you should not use `plt.hist` since `plt` wouldn't understand Pandas' Categorical. Try with `diamonds['clarity'].value_counts().plot.bar()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer